# Expiry Date not being saved

Tags: craft3, entries, saving

we are trying to take advantage of the expiry date of Entries in Craft, but have observed that this field is not being saved into the database. Any ideas why this isn't being saved?

Craft CMS 3.7.39

Comment: How are you determining/checking that the expiry date is not being saved? What behaviour are you observing, and how are you testing this? Do you have any modules or plugins running that hook into the entry save mechanism?

Comment: Changing expiry date, saving the entry.

Plugins
Admin Bar 3.1.11
Control Panel Nav 3.0.17
Dumper 2.0.0
Element API 2.8.4
Expanded Singles 1.2.0
Image Resizer 2.1.1
Mailgun 2.0.1
Redactor 2.10.7
SEO 3.7.4
Super Table 2.7.1
Twigpack 1.2.17
Two-Factor Authentication 2.10.0

Comment: Hm, difficult to tell. Try deactivating all plugins to see if one of them is messing with element saves. If this isn't the case, try updating to the latest Craft version (4.x if possible). Maybe you're seeing an issue that has already been fixed.